# Flutter app - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 for iOS Device. Flutter Package - cryptlib

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I am making use of cryptlib package in my Flutter app for encrypting login credentials.
The app is working for the Android version. But in iOS I am getting below error while trying to run on iPhone

```
    Xcode's output:
↳
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CryptlibPlugin", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find any answer >

Answer (score 0):

Yup! there is issue with the flutter cryptlib package in flutter for iOS side.
It works fine for Android.
well the developer has mentioned that he was facing with the headers part.

Still, if you want to work for the same using that package for iOS & android too.

I would recommend you to go for Method Channel.
Bind your native code and call it to the flutter side via Method Channel.

Comment: Can you put sample?